# this == null in java , After that also execution why Continues?

Tags: java

This is my code . I set null to this reference then why it prints **not null set**

Test.java

```
try
  {                
     new Test().setNull();
     System.out.println("not null set");
   }
catch (Exception e)
  {//Catch exception if any
     System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }

  }
  public  void setNull()
  {
     setNull(this);
  }
  public  void setNull(Object thisRef)
  {
      thisRef = null;
  }
```

output :
not null set

Comment: `null` doesnt cause an exception, variables can be `null`. Try calling a method on your `Test` object after you set it to `null`, that will cause an exception.

Comment: Also, you're only manipulating the local reference to the passed in object. The caller will still have a reference, so it doesn't become inaccessible. The only way you could break an object's reference to itself is to assign directly to `this`, but since `this` is a language keyword and not some weird, implicit, hidden member, you can't use it as the left side of an assignment.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen setting null will not cause `NPE`. even after setting null, calling another methods of the same class will not through NPE, since `this` is not `null`. please see my example.

Comment: @sunil If you set an object to `null` then attempt to call a method of that class on *that* object, you will receive a NPE

Comment: @HunterMcMillen you can see the working code in my answer to this post, where i am calling the `print` function after the calling `setNull()` method. Please test

Comment: @sunil You aren't actually setting the current object to `null` in your code, you are only setting the local variable `thisRef` to null. You can easily see that from your print statements.

Comment: yes I got that, thank you for your reply.....

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes... that's what i am doing in my code. Btw, is there any way by which we can set the `this` reference to null, from the current running class's member methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code is incomplete. Please post a minimal working example next time.
2. You pass `this` as parameter to `setNull()`. Keep in mind that arguments are passed by value in Java. `thisRef` is initialized to point to the same instance as this, but when you reassign `null` to `thisRef`, the value of `this` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 11):

Java is not Call by Reference. Java is not Call by Reference. Java is not ..

Assigning to a *local variable* does *not* change any argument supplied by the caller. Ever.

The function therefore "does nothing": it assigns `null` to a local variable (that is also a parameter) and returns.

Comment: you say "local variable does not change any argumen", but am passing this reference is this local variable ?.

Comment: @sunleo you won't change the reference in java only the reference _value_ - Java is pass_by_value. The reference doesn't change location in heap. EOS

Answer (score 4):

Setting a reference to `null` will not throw `NPE`, else think of how would you ever nullify your `references`?
Further, when you assign `null` to any reference, only that reference is detached from the object it is pointing to. But the remaining references will still be there.

For e.g: -

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
MyClass obj2 = obj1; 

obj1 = null;  // only obj1 is detached from object
System.out.println(obj2);  // obj2 still points to original object
```

So, when you invoke your method: -

```
new Test().setNull();
```

A copy of the reference is stored in `this` *(Java is **not pass by reference**, rather it **passes the References by value**)*, which is then again passed to another method, so one more copy is made, which then you set to null. But the original reference still points to that object.

NPE can only be thrown when you try to invoke any method, or access any object properties, on a `null` reference.

Comment: you say "local variable does not change any argument", but am passing "this" reference is this local variable ?.

Comment: @sunleo.. When you pass `this` to your `Object thisRef`. Then a copy of reference is made, which points to the same object as `this`. So, even if you make that reference - `thisRef` again point to null, `this` in caller method is still pointing to that object right.

Answer (score 1):

Just another explanation to your own example:

```
package com.test;

public class Test {

    public void setNull() {
        System.out.println("Before setting null : "+ this);
        System.out.println("Going to set null");
        this.setNull(this);
        System.out.println("'this' after setting null in caller method : "+this);

        this.print();// make sure that 'this' is not null;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Another method");
    }

    public void setNull(Object thisRef) {
        // here you are referring the 'this' object via a variable 'thisRef'
        System.out.println("Inside setNull");
        System.out.println("thisRef value : " + thisRef); // same as 'this'
        // nullifying the 'thisRef'
        thisRef = null;
        System.out.println("thisRef after nullifying : "+thisRef);// ofcourse 'thisRef' is null
        System.out.println("'this' after setting null in method : "+this); // here the 'this' object will not be null
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setNull();
    }
}
```

and the console output:

```
Before setting null : com.test.Test@3e25a5
Going to set null
Inside setNull
thisRef value : com.test.Test@3e25a5
thisRef after nullifying : null
'this' after setting null in method : com.test.Test@3e25a5
'this' after setting null in caller method : com.test.Test@3e25a5
Another method
```